# Having trouble with if-then statement logic

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am somewhat new to c# and I'm having some trouble trying to wrap my mind around this if-then statement I'm trying to implement.

Here is my goal: When a user enters an order into the system, a unique orderID is created for each order. However, some additional functionality is the user has the option to select the # of items and then a new row is created for each item using the same orderID. There is one unique key for each item. This giving you this:

```
 ORDERID     KEY     ItemCode

 ORD123      758        2
 ORD123      584        2
 ORD123      582        2
```

The issue I am having is that the ORDER ID has to be unique **unless** there is more than one item in the order (creating multiple rows per order as shown above).

What works with my current code: 
Single item Order IDs, are checked with other single item Order IDs

```
 Existing Order : ORD111
 Attempt to Enter new order of : ORD111
 **Sorry OrderID already exists**
```

Single item Order IDs, are checked against multiple item Order IDs,

```
 Existing Order : ORD222
                  ORD222
                  ORD222
 Attempt to enter new order of : ORD222
 **Sorry OrderID already exists**
```

However, when I enter a multiple item order IDs,

```
 Existing Order : ORD333
                  ORD333
                  ORD333
 Attempt to enter new order of ORD333
                               ORD333
                               ORD333
 **Order Successfully Entered**
```

Here is my code that checks for the ORDER ID

```
     private bool isOrderIDUnique()
 {
     string OrderID = txtOrderID.Text;
     string ItemAmount = txtItemAmount.Text;
     int items = Convert.ToInt32(ItemAmount);
     string select = getSelectString("COUNT(*)", strings.settings.AccessTable,  "ORDERID = '" + OrderID + "'");
     int count = CountOrderID(select);
     if (count == 0)
     {
         return true;
     }
     if (count >= 1 && items > 1)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
```

If anyone can help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it! What part am I missing from my IF Statement? How can I check groups against groups? Thanks!!

Comment: You can reduce your program to this:
    return (count==0 || items>1);

So, you are returning true if items>1. Is that what you want?

Comment: Starting from the top, you should be using multiple tables, not putting in the same orderid for multiple rows...

Comment: I use this method to check the ORDER ID before the order is entered.

Comment: Ryan, the orderID is not the primary key for each row.

Comment: kainaw, the # of items determines the # of rows. if items > 1, the program wouldnt verify a unique order ID. Thats exactly the problem i'm having.

Comment: also the if statement since you are checking if something = 0 return true and >= 1 return true you can do `if (count >=0 && items > 1){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a table redesign:

```
OrdersTable
OrderID User
1       Joe
```

Where `OrderID` is a surrogate primary key

```
OrderDetailsTable
OrderID Key ItemCode
1       XXX 1
1       XXX 2
```

Then, you only need to check for the existence of an order, not the count matching. It seems you are making this more complex than it needs to be for both yourself and your user.

Comment: +1. Normalising the database is a good first step. Let the database enforce the unique constraint.